# How can I align my logo to the left and my menu to center with Tailwind?

Tags: css, frontend, tailwind-css

I'm using tailwind for my personal portfolio. Now I have just started with the NavBar.

I want my name and logo on the left. But the menu with five items in the middle of the screen. How do I manage to do this?

I have tried `justify-Between` but this only works if i have a third item.

```
<main>
      <title>My Name - Software Engineer</title>

      <nav className="bg-black">
        <div className="max-w-6xl mx-auto border border-red-400">
          <div className="flex justify-between">

              <div>
                <a href="#" className="flex items-start py-5 px-3 text-white-700">
                  <span>My Name . _</span>
                </a>
              </div>

              <div className="flex items-center justify-between  absolute space-x-1">
                <a href="#" className="py-5 px-3 text-gray-700">Home</a>
                <a href="#" className="py-5 px-3 text-gray-700">Expertise</a>
                <a href="#" className="py-5 px-3 text-gray-700">Work</a>
                <a href="#" className="py-5 px-3 text-gray-700">Experience</a>
                <a href="#" className="py-5 px-3 text-gray-700">Contact</a>
              </div>


            <div className="flex items-end space-x-1">
              <a href="" className="py-5 px-3 text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900"></a>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
        
    </main>
```

Comment: There are lots of questions like this for CSS in general. It shouldn't be difficult to translate solutions to Tailwind. [Logo on the left and menu links centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65456315/logo-on-the-left-menu-links-centered)

Comment: The simple answer may be to put a duplicate of your logo container on the right and make it invisible. You'll have natural balance.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the "absolute". There should be "text-white" or "text-slate-700" not "text-white-700". Here is the snippet you can change class to className for jsx.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <main>
      <title>My Name - Software Engineer</title>

      <nav class="bg-black">
        <div class="max-w-6xl mx-auto border border-red-400">
          <div class="flex justify-between">

              <div class="flex-initial">
                <a href="#" class="flex items-start py-5 px-3 text-white">
                  <span>My Name . _</span>
                </a>
              </div>

              <div class="flex items-center justify-between  space-x-1">
                <a href="#" class="py-5 px-3 text-gray-700">Home</a>
                <a href="#" class="py-5 px-3 text-gray-700">Expertise</a>
                <a href="#" class="py-5 px-3 text-gray-700">Work</a>
                <a href="#" class="py-5 px-3 text-gray-700">Experience</a>
                <a href="#" class="py-5 px-3 text-gray-700">Contact</a>
              </div>


            <div class="flex items-end space-x-1">
              <a href="" class="py-5 px-3 text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900"></a>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
        
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```